# regular expression to find all cell addresses in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which may contain cell address, which is look like: 
A1, B34, Z728 - only capital letters and 
AA3, ABA92, ZABC83 - there may be several letters before Integer number. 
The typical source string is look like: 
=3+7*A1-B3*AB28 
I need to get collection of all cells in the string: A1, B3, AB28 
I tried to use Regex.Matches method with the following regular expression: @"[A..Z]+?[1..9]+?", but it doesn't work.
Can anybody help me to write the regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three errors in your regular expression:

- Character class ranges are specified with `-`, not `..`.
- Cell addresses can contain the digit 0, just not as the first digit.
- The greedy default is what you want. Your lazy matching will lose digits from the end.

Try this:

```
"[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*"
```

Example:

```
    string input = "3+7*A1-B3*AB28";
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, "[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*"))
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Output:

```
A1
B3
AB28
```